# Passing AngularJS expression to PHP or Ajax alternative

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

In a PHP/HTML file I have an AngularJS expression as follows:

```
{{data.po_id}}
```

It is included as `<td>{{data.po_id}}</td>` in a table row.

I need to use this expression as param for a PHP function, like this:

```
<?php echo "Numero de objetos = ".recuperar_poitems({{data.po_id}})?>
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

I ask you to explain me a way to pass the value of `{{data.po_id}}` to a PHP variable or another way to get the return value of the PHP function `recuperar_poitems($variable)` using AJAX or JQuery and the above mentioned AngularJS expression.

The function `recuperar_poitems($variable)` is included on a php file in the same remote folder as the PHP/HTML file.

EDIT

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('ajax/getPO.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

Comment: [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is your friend ^^

Comment: Thank you @moonwave99. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a $http.post request (Angular js) to your php with your array, you can do it this way (i assume that is data.po_id is an array):

```
myapp.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.post('urlToYourPHP', data).success(function(response) {
    $scope.data.po_id = response;
  });
}]);
```

And in php you would loop through the array like this:

```
$po_id = json_decode($_POST['po_id']);

foreach($po_id as $key => $value) {
    $po_id[$key] = recuperar_poitems($value);
}

echo json_encode($po_id);
```

And then you have your array parsed through your function

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am new to Angular JS. You mean to include the $http.post request inside the <td> tag as <script> ??

Comment: No you have to do it in your controller in your central JS file, if you don't have a controller i would recommend making one.

Comment: I am using a js file to retrieve the data from the database that is called from the PHP/HTML file to get the expressions like {{data.po_id}}. Is that the controller you mean?

Comment: Yeah, if you have a controller in it. If you don't know what a controller is look at this http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: The JS file has a controller in it, but I guess I am not able to do what you mean. After including your $http.post request, how do I call the received data to be put inside the <td> tag?

Comment: I have included the JS file as EDIT in my question.

Comment: If you have added the controller to the html page, you should just write what you did in your question because of the $scope

Comment: The controller is added to the html page, then it is the source that populates the table.

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I am not sure to fully understand what I have to do.